# Random Lottery Number Generator without repeat sets?

Tags: python

Random gen() picks a repeated number, the same number as 33, 33, in a list. I want to get a different list from numbers [0.99]. What method should be used to fix the bug?

Comment: add them to a set() until the len of the set() is long enough?

Comment: Please post some actual code that demonstrates the problem you are having. Nobody knows what "Random gen()" is or does. Without knowing what, specifically, you are trying to do, it's not clear that *there is* a bug, let alone how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

the [random](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) library provide you with a function for this in [sample](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample)

```
>>> import random
>>> random.sample(range(100),5)
[86, 27, 78, 74, 57]
>>>
```

if you only want one number you can use either [choice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) or [randint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint)

```
>>> random.choice(range(100))
23
>>> random.randint(0,99)
77
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `numpy` solution using [`np.random.choice()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html). Setting the flag `replace=False` avoids duplicates.

```
import numpy as np

draws = 6
np.random.choice(range(0,100), draws, replace=False)
```

Instead of passing `range(100)`, you could also pass 100, which will return numbers between 0-99.

**Output:**

```
array([76, 74,  2, 37, 96, 41])
```

Comment: numpy is like a little overkill, the standard library random module provide functions for this

Answer (score 0):

```
# import random (library to generate random numbers)
import random

# declare a variable l_number (lottery number) using the function random.choice()
l_number = random.choice(range(0, 100))

# print the lottery number
print(l_number)
```